# sorting struct function alphabetically and rearranging it's members

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I am still a beginner in c++ programming and I have already tried searching, but another problem arises.

So I want the user to input the student's name and 4 quizScore. I want the names I inputted to be sorted alphabetically, and I still haven't solved that yet.

Furthermore, another problem arises: if I sort my variable names, the quiz score will not be sorted the way my name variables were arranged.

So basically, if I sort my variable name, I want the array quizeScores to be arranged in the same element as how the user inputted the data. I really need your help. I know my code is not the best and do love to have it revised. Thank you so much. Please help me...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct studen_grades {
string name;
int studentQuiz [1][4];
}records[5];


int main () {

double average = 0.0;
int x = 0, y = 0, recountFlag = 0, flag = 0;
bool repeat = true;
char addStudent = 'y';
string tempt;

    cout << "Enter the number of students to input : ";
    cin >> flag;
    
    
    //input
    
    for (x = 0; x < flag; x++) {
        
        cout << "Enter student name (all-cap) : ";
        cin >> records[x].name;
        
            for (y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
                
                cout << "Enter score in quiz " << y + 1 << " : ";
                cin >> records[x].studentQuiz[x][y];
            }
    }
    
    //sort the variable alphabetically
    
    
    
    
    
    //Display the data
    
        cout << "=============================================================================" << endl;
        printf ("%-40s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s\n", "Student Name", "Quiz1", "Quiz2", "Quiz3", "Quiz4");
        cout << "=============================================================================" << endl;
    
    for (x = 0; x < flag; x++) {
        
            printf ("%-40s", records[x].name.c_str());
        for (y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
            
            printf ("%-10d", records[x].studentQuiz[x][y]);
        }
        
        cout << "\n";
    }
 }
```

Comment: So, where's the sorting code that you're having trouble with? If you were asking for someone to write the sorting code for you, sorry, we don't do that here, we don't write code for other people, we only answer ***specific*** questions on programming topics. Before posting their first question on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here. Not doing any of this results in a poor quality question almost every time. It then gets downvoted, closed, and then deleted.

Comment: I doubt you really want a 2d array here `int studentQuiz [1][4];` especially since you're accessing it out of bounds all over the place. Just use an array of 4 ints to hold 4 scores.

Answer (score 1):

ask yourself (or you rubber duck https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

"if this struct holds the information for one student why is the studentQuiz a 2d array?"

```
struct studen_grades {
 string name;
 int studentQuiz [1][4]; <<<===?
}records[5];
```

surely you mean

```
struct studen_grades {
 string name;
 int studentQuiz [4]; <<<===
}records[5];
```

Now you can see why this blows up

```
for (x = 0; x < flag; x++) {
    
    printf ("%-40s", records[x].name.c_str());
    for (y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
        
        printf ("%-10d", records[x].studentQuiz[x][y]); <<== x is > 0
    }
    
    cout << "\n";
}
```

should be

```
for (x = 0; x < flag; x++) {
    
        printf ("%-40s", records[x].name.c_str());
    for (y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
        
        printf ("%-10d", records[x].studentQuiz[y]);
    }
    
    cout << "\n";
}
```

and here too

```
 cin >> records[x].studentQuiz[x][y];
 -----------------------------+++
```

Also this is c++ code why arent you using cout instead of printf

Of course there is no sort here. But at least you now have code that loads the data and prints it correctly.

Finally, note that you should really be using `std::vector` for the students rather than a fixed array